# Convert text file of arrays into a Python list

Tags: python, text

My text file consists of a sequence of arrays all on the same line (i.e. no indentations). I'm trying to take these arrays and put them into a python list.

The text file is like this:

```
[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,5],[1,2,3,6],[1,2,3,7],[1,2,3,8],[1,2,3,9],[1,2,3,10]........
```

I'm trying to take this and make a list of lists such as:

```
[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,5],[1,2,3,6],[1,2,3,7],[1,2,3,8],[1,2,3,9],[1,2,3,10]]
```

I tried using the read method but all I get is one giant string.

Comment: Can you share how you got that giant string and how it looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `read()` in your file and save it to a variable (equivalent to this):

```
a = '[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,5],[1,2,3,6],[1,2,3,7],[1,2,3,8],[1,2,3,9],[1,2,3,10]'
```

If you don't want to use `eval()`, you can use the safer `ast.literal_eval()`:

```
import ast
list(ast.literal_eval(a))
```

If you don't want to use any kind of evaluation, you can use built-ins and string methods:

```
[list(map(int, line.split(','))) for line in a.strip('[]').split('],[')]
```

These will all produce the following:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 6], [1, 2, 3, 7], [1, 2, 3, 8], [1, 2, 3, 9], [1, 2, 3, 10]]
```